# Windows 7 Administrator HomeUsers Account 2

Tags: windows-7

how may I remove administrator password using another account?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the default admin account, it's disabled by default, so you would first have to enable it (using an account that's also in the administrator's group), the reset the password to a blank one, and if you do that I also recommend disabling the account again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this website to find out how to activate the built in administrator password.
If you already have an account with administrative rights, follow these steps:
- open the control panel, 
- user accounts
- manage another account
- select the account of which you want to change it's password.
thats it.

If you do not a administrative user which you can use, then look at this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSlMyKfaT0A